# Why do contents only show up for one user at a time while using firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to know why do contents only show up for one user at a time.

For example: if `personA@gmail.com` is logged in, uploads a file on the browser with the intention that other users are able to see it and  afterwards, `personA@gmail.com` decide to logout for whatever reason.  Now, `personB@gmail.com` logs in.  How can you make it where, when logged in, `personB@gmail.com` can see the content `personA@gmail.com` uploaded (the file)?

I'm not too sure what to search hence why I'm asking this here.

Security file below:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your security rules file?

Comment: @Jonathan Sure, I'd love to but where can I find that?

Comment: If you goto the firebase console -> Storage -> Rules. This is where you can set all the rules for security of the storage

Comment: Please update your question with the rules and the structure you are saving the files and retrieve the files.

Comment: @Jonathan Done.  I posted the security rules file.

Comment: Can you also share the code you are using to read the files?

Comment: @Jonathan Posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adjusting the security of the rules which you will want to do for a situation like this. To lock down the files to only **authenticated** users, use this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
   }
 }
}
```

There are also some great documents here [Storage Security Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start?authuser=0)

Comment: So with the snippet you just provided, that would satisfy the scenario that I'm referring to, corrent?

Comment: The code I provided is only for the security of allowing authenticated users to see files. From your question it sounds like you are wanting User B to see User A's files. Most likely it is an issue of what path you are using to read the files. From your updated code sample I can't tell what that path is.

Comment: Yeah so you mean with the security code you provided, authenticated users can now see each others uploads and the security code that I provided disallows this, correct?

Comment: Your security rules allowed unauthorized users to upload and read files.

Comment: ok got it, so what does your security rules exactly do?  allows only authenticated to see uploaded files, right?

Comment: The one I provided only allows authenticated users to read and write. You can get very complex rules from that starting point. I would suggest reviewing the documentation more on that and there are some good youtube videos that go pretty deep into the topic.

Comment: Thanks, just mark my answer as answered if that works for you.